# Banach space and weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T ∈\mathcal{L}(X,Y)$ (continuous mapping from $X$ to $Y$), where $X$ and $Y$ are infinite dimensional Banach spaces. For each sequence $(x_n)_n≥1$ in $X$ and for each $x ∈ X$, show that $x_n → x $ convergence weakly, as $n →∞$, implies $Tx_n → Tx$ convergence weakly, as $n →∞$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $y^{\ast}\in Y^{\ast}$, then $y^{\ast}\circ T\in X^{\ast}$. But $y^{\ast}\circ T$ is continuous as norm-to-scalar, then it must be continuous as weak-to-scalar, so $y^{\ast}\circ T(x_{n})\rightarrow y^{\ast}\circ T(x)$, that is, $y^{\ast}(T(x_{n}))\rightarrow y^{\ast}(T(x))$.

Note that $\|y^{\ast}\circ T\|\leq\|y^{\ast}\|\|T\|<\infty$ since $T$ is norm-to-norm continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I am not sure I can follow you. *?

Comment: Which part of the statement?

Comment: Why *? and what do you mean with weak-to scalar?

Comment: $Y^{\ast}$ is the set of all bounded linear maps from $Y$ to scalar, the boundedness here is equivalent to the continuity of $(Y,\|\cdot\|)\rightarrow{\bf{F}}$, where ${\bf{F}}$ is the scalar field, this is what I meant norm-to-scalar.